# Replace function of a button on iOS default keyboard

Tags: iphone

I had known how to create a custom keyboard. But my problem now is I can replace some button on default keyboard with my own button or I can add more button on it

Like this: I want to replace button "A", when tap that button it will insert "B" or some thing I want instead of "A"

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you're not necessarily looking to replace the "A" on the keyboard with a "B" but rather, you want a "B" to be inserted instead of an "A". This can be accomplished by assigning a delegate for the `UITextField`/`UITextView` and implementing the corresponding *shouldChange* method.

*If you use a **UITextField**, implement:*

```
- (BOOL) textField: (UITextField *) textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange: (NSRange) range replacementString: (NSString *) string
```

*If you use a **UITextView**, implement:*

```
- (BOOL) textView: (UITextView *) textView shouldChangeTextInRange: (NSRange) range replacementText: (NSString *) text
```

Within either of these methods you can intercept the change to the text field or text view and then change its contents to what you want.

For example, if you were to use a `UITextField`, it would look like this:

```
- (BOOL) textField: (UITextField *) textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange: (NSRange) range replacementString: (NSString *) string {

    BOOL shouldChange = YES;

    if ([@"A" isEqualToString: string]) {
        shouldChange = NO;
        [textField setText: [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange: range withString: @"B"]];
    }

    return shouldChange;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! How about others button like return, hidekeyboard. I can change their function. Like the "hidekeyboard" button now I don't want it hids the keyboard, I want it does somethingelse. It's possible?

Comment: Yes, it might be possible. You'll have to look at different delegate methods like `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField` or `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField` for potentially accomplishing these other behaviors.

Comment: I'm very appreciate with your help. But it doesn't help my problem

Comment: What specific problem are you trying to address?